# Need Help Making a Dynamic Chart

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, charts

Good afternoon! I am a college student who is Co-oping for a chemical company over the summer. I have completed one very basic course in Excel VBA programming, so I lack a solid foundation of how the language works.

Recently, I was given the task of building upon a code one of my predecessors wrote, with the intent that it would generate dynamic graphs.

The objective is this: Write a code that will display my company's 17 different products over a 2 year period on 4 different graphs (one per reactor). The workbook has about six different sheets of data, one of which has a button that the user will press to initiate all the necessary data calculations, cell population, and graph generation.

There is no way to know how many batches of each of our 17 products we will make over the course of 2 years since that is dependent on customer demand. My code needs to dynamically account for this.

I have reviewed my class material from two years ago and purchased John Walkenbach's 2015 VBA Power Programming Book. I am teaching myself VBA code, but still do not fully understand how some of it works. It is my hope that someone here may be able to explain why my code is not working and what I should do to fix it.

I started very simply with the intent to graph a single product's two batches using the overall time it took to make each batch (cycle time) and the dates on which the batches finished as my y and x values, respectively. The code looked like this:

```
Sub Chart_Excerpt()

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "G350 Charts"
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Biyearly  Report'!$CY$802:$CY$803"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Biyearly  Report'!$CZ$802:$CZ$803"   

End Sub
```

That code works, however, it is not dynamic. I tried altering the last two lines before End Sub to be this instead:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range (Cells(802, 103), Cells(803, 103))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range (Cells(802, 104), Cells(803, 104))
```

I then tried to replace the specific, non-dynamic references with something better such as abc and xyz:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range (Cells(abc, 103), Cells(xyz, 103))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range (Cells(abc, 104), Cells(xyz, 104))
```

Where abc and xyz are the first and last rows of the data selection, respectively. They were calculated using a simple formula that I verified works correctly and is based on a section of code written by a former Co-op student. The data entry is vertical, so the column numbers will be constant while the number of rows will change depending on the number of batches we make per product.

This didn't work, so I took the variables out and retyped the specific references 802 to 803. To my surprise, that also didn't work. I've learned since then that Excel VBA reads data as arrays for Series Collection, so I know I must have set myself up for failure by attempting to force it to read a Range.

However, it isn't working for my arrays either. Below is my new code:

```
Sub Chart_Excerpt()
Dim A() As Double, AA as Integer, s as Series, Result as Variant, N as Integer

'''Everything in above excerpt here [], but commented to be inactive

Call Data_Series

End Sub
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Sub Data_Series
Dim XRange as Range, YRange as Range, Result as Variant, s as Series

'AA is calculated like the xyz example above and provides a good value
'AA and CC2311endrowBR are defined as 'Public AA as Integer' and _
     'Public CC2231endrowBR as Integer' in my code
AA = CC2311endrowBR
ReDim A(802 To AA, 103 To 104)

Call Read_Data_G350_CC2311(A, N, 0, 0)

Set s = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Chart.SeriesCollection

Result = A(s)

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    Set XRange = Range(Result())
    Set YRange = Range(Result())
        s.XValues = XRange
        s.Values = YRange

End Sub
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Sub Read_Data_G350_CC2311(A() as Double, N as Integer, R as Integer, C as Integer)
Dim i as Integer, j as Integer

N = AA
'AA is defined as 'Public AA as Integer' in my code

For i = 802 to N
    For j = 103 to 104
        A(i, j) = Cells(i+R, j+C)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I continue to receive error messages along the lines of "Subscript out of Range," "User Defined Error," "Object Missing," etc. Is there a way to dynamically code for a chart like this? Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I should try next?

**Update:**

I was able to complete the code and it is working perfectly! Thank you to Byron for pointing me in the right direction!

Below is the new, working code in case anyone else comes with a similar problem and needs assistance:

```
Sub Graphing_for_G350(xval As Range, yval As Range, location As Integer)
 Dim height As Double, width As Double, columns As Integer, cht_obj As ChartObject, ser As Series
 Dim k As Integer, SIndex As Integer, a As Double, j As Integer, n As Integer

'Determines Chart size and location
 height = 300
 width = 300
 columns = 1

 j = 0
 k = 0
 n = 0

Set cht_obj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add((1 Mod columns) * width, (1 \ columns) * height, width, height)


'Determines the Series order based on product order in my company's spreadsheet
 For SIndex = 1 To 17

  If SIndex = 1 And CC2311endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = CC2311endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 2 And dr22endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = dr22endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 3 And dr22NCendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = dr22NCendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 4 And NCYendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = NCYendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 5 And RE100LendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE100LendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 6 And RE100XLendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE100XLendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 7 And RE105endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE105endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 8 And RE110endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE110endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 9 And RE25endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE25endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 10 And RE80HPendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE80HPendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 11 And RE85endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE85endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 12 And RE85KendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE85KendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 13 And RE85LendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE85LendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 14 And RE85LKendrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE85LKendrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 15 And RE98endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = RE98endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 16 And XR4318endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = XR4318endrowBR
     ElseIf SIndex = 17 And XR4265endrowBR > 801 Then
         a = XR4265endrowBR
     Else
     End If


'This loop for j determines the xval columns of the Series.
          If j = 0 Then
             j = 103
          ElseIf j > 0 Then
              j = j + 3
          End If

'This loop for n determines the yval columns of the Series.
          If n = 0 Then
             n = 104
          ElseIf n > 0 Then
              n = n + 3
          End If


'This determines the range with respect to the product just chosen in the If-Then statements above.
     Set xval = Range(Cells(802, j), Cells(a, j))
     Set yval = Range(Cells(802, n), Cells(a, n))

'Now to add the Series and name it.
     Set ser = cht_obj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         With ser
         ser.ChartType = xlXYScatter

 'This loop for k determines the name of the Series.
          If k = 0 Then  
             k = 102
          ElseIf k > 0 Then
              k = k + 3
          End If

'Defines Series Name and Values
         ser.Name = Cells(802, k)
         ser.Values = yval
         ser.XValues = xval
        End With  

 'Iterates the next Series Index to decide the next Series.
 Next SIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your actual code really have the `m` instead of a `,` in the `Range(Cells()m Cells()` bit?  That will cause problems.  Also, `Charts` can be created with `Ranges` and that is the preferred way to do it to make it dynamic.  See this answer for a very simple look at how to create a chart with VBA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715656/excel-multiple-dynamic-graphs/29720112#29720112

Comment: Regarding how to get the `Ranges` to be dynamic, you need to look into functions like `Range.End()`, `Range.Offset()`, and `Range.Resize()` which will allow you to "build" a `Range` based on dynamic information either contained in the code or the spreadsheet.  Other tricks include: used named ranges in the spreadsheet and refer to them in VBA, looping through cells with `For` or `For Each` to build ranges based on cell contents, etc.  More specific questions will get more specific answers on that front.

Comment: Thank you Byron! No, the m's are not in my actual code; that is a typo I missed. Thank you for pointing that out. I will try out your suggestions and see what I can do. Have a great weekend!

Comment: I wrote a new code using your suggestions and that link. It seems to be working well! Once I've fully tested it, I'll post it here for reference in case anyone else has a similar problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you could think a different way of doing this, what would i do? i would create a dinamic table in a hidden sheet and pull a slider from it, from there, pull the dinamic graph from the dinamic table, and my macro would change the selection in the slider, that will make my graph dinamic, other way to do this, if you already know the columns that you are going to show (sumifs(...)), you could simple use a series of formulas and point the graph to those formulas, and my macro would only change a keyword that my formulas use to get that keyword(product) information.