# Multiple charts in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts, range

I am working on my research and I have to generate more than 91 charts for each sheet and I would like to use macro to do that.

I am still new with macros but I tried to write this one, but it is not working. I would greatly appreciate your help on this issue!

The set of data that I have looks like this

```
> A1         B1     C1    D1    E1     F1    G1       H1    I1
> 
> 
> Period    Ratio       Period  Ratio       Period  ratio   
> 2000Q1    1.23        2000Q1  0.78        2000Q1  1.07    
> 2000Q2    1.43        2000Q2  1.12        2000Q2  0.76     2000Q3 1.8        
> 2000Q3    1.09        2000Q3  1.21
```

(under Columns A & B I have Period and Ratio) - then Column C is empty - then (under column D & E I have Period and Ratio) and so on.

I separated the data set with an empty column.

Please note that the are other rows (I have an update button that I every time I click a new row with (period- ratio) will be added for all the columns)- also the first row with values starts at row 3

I want to create a chart for each set of data (here 3 charts)

The macro I wrote is a follows:

```
Sub loopChart()
Dim mychart As Chart
Dim c As Integer
Sheets("analysis").Select

c = 1
While c <> 0 #I put this condition so that the code will know that I have no more data set

    Set mychart = Charts.Add
    mychart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(cells(3, c)).CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    c = c + 3
Wend

For Each mychart In Sheets("class").ChartObjects
    mychart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
Next mychart

End Sub
```

I am not too sure of what I am doing is correct, but I am facing a trouble with the range. Also I know that this macro will create a new chart-sheet.

how can I create all the charts on the "analysis" sheet next to the values?

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help!!

Comment: What does `it is not working` mean?  Please add a picture of the output or a description of what is wrong.  Depending on that, you might want to take a look at [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720112/4288101) to create charts via VBA.  `SetSourceData` tends to put you at the mercy of how Excel interprets the `Range` you want to plot.  Defining the `Series` directly makes it much easier to build the `Chart` you want.

Answer (score 2):

my friend. A workbook can have charts directly, or it can have charts integrated in worksheets. It depends on what you want. Excel is an object-oriented program. The `Range.CurrentRegion` should work, but if there were any filled cells around, it might cause problem.

Try this :

```
Sub loopChart()

Dim mychart As Chart
Dim myRange As range
Dim c As Integer
c = 1

While c <= 7 '1=dataSource1, 4=dataSource2, 7=dataSource3
    'set data source for the next chart
    With Worksheets("class")
        Set myRange = .range(.Cells(3, c), .Cells(6, c + 1))
    End With

    'create chart
    Sheets("analysis").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

        With ActiveChart
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers 'xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=myRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns  'sets source data for graph including labels
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)  'including legend
            .HasTitle = True
            'dimentions & location:
            .Parent.Top = 244  'defines the coordinates of the top of the chart
            .Parent.Left = c * 100  'defines the coordinates for the left side of the chart
            .Parent.Height = 200
            .Parent.Width = 300
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Title here"
        End With

    c = c + 3
Wend

End Sub
```

Result :
[image: Screenshot]

For further cases, you can visit the Microsoft Office Dev Center:
[Creating Charts in Excel 2003 Using Visual Basic for Applications Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203725(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the charts on the `analysis` `Worksheet`, you can change the `Location` when the chart is created.  I also changed the sheet name in the second loop to match the sheet name.  You can add this line of code to the first loop though; the second loop is not necessary.  If you do that, be sure to set a new reference to `mychart` on the location line.

```
Sub loopChart()
Dim mychart As Chart
Dim c As Integer
Sheets("analysis").Select

c = 1
While c <> 0 #I put this condition so that the code will know that I have no more data set

    Set mychart = Charts.Add
    mychart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(cells(3, c)).CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    'change location to sheet
    mychart.Location xlLocationAsObject, "analysis"
    c = c + 3
Wend

For Each mychart In Sheets("analysis").ChartObjects
    mychart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
Next mychart

End Sub
```