# VBA code for plotting two separate charts for alternate columns

Tags: excel, vba

[This](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=4975315e5e&view=fimg&th=14e49324450b94b8&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_ibkmqwye0&safe=1&attbid=ANGjdJ-YlHlj0DInSTwrvjoQ-xqHjMpnIGL0ia-T5S7-6cjqAxSBBE5p2fXMIz8SorKHukyT0xMrBcAYUUhxOaUcXeGsBht5Ao0RQ3JKFfjFXRDpn2P9zwHsE7pAY-M&ats=1435749492411&rm=14e49324450b94b8&zw&sz=w1342-h523) is the part of the large data set I have. I want to plot two separate charts for the 'Actual' and '% of total'.

This is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ChartRange1 As Range
Dim ChartRange2 As Range

`StrtRow = 1
 StartRow = 3
 EndRow = 6

With Sheets("Sheet1")

Set ChartRange1 = Range(Cells(StrtRow, "B"), Cells(EndRow, "B"))
ChartRange1Addr = ChartRange1.Address(External:=True)

 Set ChartRange2 = Range(Cells(StrtRow, "C"), Cells(EndRow, "J"))
ChartRange2Addr = ChartRange2.Address(External:=True)
End With

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

'We set the source data for the chart (y,x)


ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
ChartRange1Addr & "," & ChartRange2Addr)


'We define the type of chart

ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

' Before we can perform an action on the chart we need to activate it
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
'We perform the cut operation
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Cut
'we select the Sheet2 where we wish to paste our chart
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'We now paste the chart in the Sheet2 whic has become the active sheet after selection
    ActiveSheet.Paste
'we return to sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
' we select the cell F9 in sheet1
    Range("F9").Activate

End Sub
```

It gives me the Actual and % plots in same chart. I have tried code for selecting alternate columns and plotting two charts, but it did not work.

[This](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=4975315e5e&view=fimg&th=14e49354ed58ce41&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_ibkmvd2y1&safe=1&attbid=ANGjdJ9ZdaI9cI224Ca5A3o76SP8rLtkcO3jm09mXnO1ZDaKhMzVpqswi_vKFjIKPNTq9-eU_DQF6aqTCvV2VGK6w0q7KNS_NIi1WeiUVspCKB1qcf6I3FTkR1IBG8M&ats=1435749492414&rm=14e49354ed58ce41&zw&sz=w1342-h523) is the chart I got. Please suggest where I can amend my code to make two separate charts for alternate columns - one for 'Actual' and the other for '% of total' values.

Comment: Have you done what you want to do manually with the macro recorder turned on? You only have one instance of .AddChart - why should it be surprising that it only adds one chart?

Comment: Generally using `SetSourceData` limits you to however Excel wants to interpret your ranges.  It is better to build the `Series` and define the ranges explicitly.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715656/excel-multiple-dynamic-graphs/29720112#29720112) for an example of how to create a chart.  It is possible to add a second series with another call to `SeriesCollection.NewSeries` or a second chart by simply calling the `Sub` a second time with different ranges.

Comment: Your images are not accessible since you linked to your Gmail account.  Please [edit] your post to include links that accessible to others.  I will edit them into the question as proper images.